# Webpage without author, using the title can make a very long apa citation

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @book{forbes,
    author = {},
    year = {2013},
    title = {Supremes Unsympathetic to Farmer's Deception at Center of Monsanto GMO Soybean SCOTUS Patent Challenge},
    note = {\url{http://www.forbes.com/sites/jonentine/2013/02/19/farmers-deception-at-center-of-monsanto-gmo-soybean-scotus-patent-challenge-genetic-innovation-threatened/}}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

That's a long ref \cite{forbes}.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sentence with an extremely long webpage title cited as a reference]

The APA reference suggests shortening titles when cited, such as (Supremes Unsympathetic, 2013) for the above example. Of course I can edit the title in BibDesk, but then the list of references contains the abbreviated title. How should I handle this?

Comment: If you use biblatex with its apa style, you can use the "shorttitle" field and the citation uses this.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `key` field for such situations, namely:

```
  @book{forbes,
    author = {},
    year = {2013},
    key = {Supremes Unsympathetic},
    title = {Supremes Unsympathetic to Farmer's Deception at Center of Monsanto GMO Soybean SCOTUS Patent Challenge},
    note = {\url{http://www.forbes.com/sites/jonentine/2013/02/19/farmers-deception-at-center-of-monsanto-gmo-soybean-scotus-patent-challenge-genetic-innovation-threatened/}}
  }
```

Comment: For other BibDesk users: I used the field editor in BibDesk to add the Key field.